# 500 error when trying to upgrade from 3.6.2 to 3.6.5

Tags: joomla-3.x, upgrade, error-handling

I am tyring to upgrade my joomla to the latest version(3.6.2 to 3.6.5), but no matter I install it online or download the package and install from local, I got a 500 error. Also when I try to open components->akeeba I get a 500 error too.  I host the website on my own linode server, when I check apache error log where I usually go to find the error logs, I didn't find anything. By the way, my front-end works well and there is no problem with other functions on back-end.

Where could the error log be and more importantly how to solve this upgrading problem? Without being able to see the detail of the 500 error, I am lost.

Comment: I would assume that this comes from a system plugin and look at the Joomla logs which is where plugins should write their reports. Barring that you can just disable system plugins one by one until it works. Typically it would be a compatibility issue caused by forgetting to upgrade something, so just upgrading all possible extensions could also be enough. Not making an answer since there is not enough information IMHO.

Comment: A bit confused of what isn't working and when/where you get the 500 errors because you said later that front-end parts of the backend work. For the 500 error it's very likely that important files that are needed by Joomla or extensions are missing or are corrupted and this sometimes causes server to report 500 error. So make sure all needed files are there and up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

From phpMyAdmin, disable system plugins one by one (highest IDs first) until the problem is no more (then you will be able to find the culprit). You can also disable system plugins by just renaming their folder to `pluginname_old` in the `plugins/system` folder.

Of course, I am assuming that you have set your error reporting to maximum in your configuration settings, but are still seeing the 500 error.